# Excel check if any values are present in more than one range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have 5 little groups of cells on my spreadsheet, set out like this:

```
      PERSON 1
       AM    PM
MON
TUE
WED
THUR
FRI

      PERSON 2
       AM    PM
MON
TUE
WED
THUR
FRI
```

etc...

The user then attributes certain values to each person, for their AM and PM for each day. My difficulty comes from the fact that each individual person may have the same value assigned to them throughout the week, but two people can not have the same value at all. If we pretended that these values were chores, then the following would be allowable:

```
      PERSON 1
       AM    PM
MON   clean  wash
TUE
WED         clean
THUR
FRI

      PERSON 2
       AM    PM
MON   iron
TUE   hoover
WED
THUR
FRI
```

but this would not be, as two different people are assigned to clean, even though they are not at the same time:

```
      PERSON 1
       AM    PM
MON   clean  wash
TUE
WED         clean
THUR
FRI

      PERSON 2
       AM    PM
MON          clean
TUE   hoover
WED
THUR
FRI
```

I need to find a suitable way to alert the user of an error like this, either through showing a message or through formatting. I cannot use the conditional formatting option 'duplicates' because this will highlight duplicates within the same person's list, which is allowed.

This formula (`SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5)-1)*(A1:A5<>""))>0`) works to find if any value is duplicated within a range, however my attempts to modify it to apply the logic to two different ranges doesn't seem to work. (For example, `SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:A5,A10:A15)-1)*(A1:A5<>"")*(A10:A15<>""))>0`)

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could easily check for duplicate values in other ranges, without having to do separate `countif`s for each possible condition, which is currently the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Is it an option to combine these ranges and use a Person column for their name? If not, are the ranges equally spaced from one another? i.e. is Person 2's MON row always 8 rows beneath Person 1's MON row?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution with the existing excel functions? I imagine this would be easier to solve using a VBA macro.